# insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, sqlalchemy

I am performing a sql in the structure of

```
SELECT “about 30 fields”
FROM “9 tables with around 10 INNER JOINs (two of the tables have around 13 million rows)”
WHERE “one LIKE string matching and two equals clauses”
```

And get the error of

> Could not allocate a new page for database 'TEMPDB' because of
>   insufficient disk space in filegroup 'DEFAULT'. Create the necessary
>   space by dropping objects in the filegroup, adding additional files to
>   the filegroup, or setting autogrowth on for existing files in the
>   filegroup.

The tempdb in System Databases Maxsize is limited to around 250G, so I tried to edit the Maxsize of “tempdb”. It seems like I do not have the privilege.

> User does not have permission to alter database ‘tempdb’, the database
>   does not exist, or the database is not in a state that allows access
>   checks. (Microsoft SQL Server, Error: 5011)

I also checked the Information of the database that I am working with (not database ‘tempdb’). The Rows Data have a Maxsize of “unlimited space”

Is there any work around to this? For example, write sql script in a way that can get the sql result in batch incrementally?

Note 1: I tried to run the script first in Python with sqlalchemy engine. Then tried in SQL Server Management Studio. The error exists in both cases.

Note2: If I change the LIKE string matching (LIKE N'% targetword') in WHERE clause to a equals clause, the query runs well.

Comment: what about using this query in some api for sqlserver is it spool whole data without message?

Comment: IF you want help how to reduce tempdb usage, you should post the actual query and execution plan.

Comment: WoW.. from 9 tables and only 2 equals. Seem like this 13 millions would grow to billions

Comment: When you start maxing tempdb with 250GB of space it is time to evaluate your query and see if it is really doing what you want.

Comment: @Dmitry.Samborskyi Thanks. I am new to spooling. Does this skip creating a temperate table in system tempdb?

Comment: @JamesZ Thanks. The idea of checking execution plan is great. Due to the query contains information in a production setting I can not post the raw query. However, I followed your suggestion and found the bottleneck are (1) Clustered Index Scan (Clustered) (26%) followed by "Hash Match (Inner Join) over a 10 million row table (29%) "  The other is "Clustered Index Scan (Clustered)". (2) Clustered Index Scan (Clustered) over a 10 million row table (26%). What Clustered Index Scan (Clustered) means? Does it need to create a large tempdb table?

Comment: @SeanLange Thanks. I will try to collect more information to optimize the query.

Comment: Your table / column names contain secret things? At least post the query plan somewhere, without it people aren't going to understand what your query does and ideas might be wrong.

Comment: All those index scans mean your query is nonSARGable. In other words, it is not able to use an indexes and is forcing sql to look at every single row to determine if the row should be included or not. When you have tables with row counts in the millions this equates to massive tempdb usage. Unless you can post the query we are left guessing and as such will not be able to help you.

Comment: Thank you all. Your suggestions already helped me understand the problem better and lead me to a good direction of trouble shooting. I will keep working on optimizing it.

Answer (score 0):

The hard disk or lun, does not have more physical space. You have filled up the drive. If you need to you can add a file on another drive to the filegroup.